org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KnownTypeLibrary with qualifiers
Because of research needs. I need to run this github repository.
https://github.com/hjc851/SPPlagiarise
java version

java version "11.0.22" 2024-01-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.22+9-LTS-219)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.22+9-LTS-219, mixed mode)

Kotlin version

Kotlin version 1.9.24-release-822 (JRE 1.8.0_401-b10)

Gradle version

Gradle 4.1
Build time: 2017-08-07 14:38:48 UTC
Revision: 941559e020f6c357ebb08d5c67acdb858a3defc2
Groovy: 2.4.11
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015
JVM: 1.8.0_401 (Oracle Corporation 25.401-b10)

I encountered some difficulties during the process.

Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KnownTypeLibrary with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private spplagiarise.obfuscation.util.SwitchToIfFilter.knownTypes
at spplagiarise.obfuscation.util.SwitchToIfFilter.knownTypes(SwitchToIfFilter.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class spplagiarise.ast.KnownTypeLibrary is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: [unknown].
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:378)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:290)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:143)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:164)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:526)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:64)
at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:62)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:62)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:55)
at org.jboss.weld.executor.CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.lambda$wrap$0(CommonForkJoinPoolExecutorServices.java:70)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask$AdaptedCallable.exec(ForkJoinTask.java:1448)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Exception 1 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: Exception List with 9 exceptions:
Exception 0 :
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type KnownTypeLibrary with qualifiers @Default
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private spplagiarise.obfuscation.util.SwitchToIfFilter.knownTypes
at spplagiarise.obfuscation.util.SwitchToIfFilter.knownTypes(SwitchToIfFilter.java:0)
dependencies for type DeferredNameMappingContext with qualifiers @Default
WELD-001474: Class spplagiarise.ast.KnownTypeLibrary is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: [unknown].
at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private spplagiarise.obfuscation.filters.DeclareRedundantConstantsFilter.mappingContext
at spplagiarise.obfuscation.filters.DeclareRedundantConstantsFilter.mappingContext(DeclareRedundantConstantsFilter.java:0)
WELD-001474: Class spplagiarise.naming.DeferredNameMappingContext is on the classpath, but was ignored because a class it references was not found: [unknown].
...

package spplagiarise.ast

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ITypeBinding
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class KnownTypeLibrary {
    lateinit var stringType: ITypeBinding
    lateinit var charType: ITypeBinding
    lateinit var intType: ITypeBinding
    lateinit var doubleType: ITypeBinding
    lateinit var voidType: ITypeBinding
    lateinit var booleanType: ITypeBinding
}

package spplagiarise.obfuscation.util

import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.IVariableBinding
import org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.InfixExpression
import spplagiarise.analytics.IAnalyticContext
import spplagiarise.ast.KnownTypeLibrary
import spplagiarise.dst.*
import spplagiarise.obfuscation.DSTObfuscatorFilter
import javax.inject.Inject
import javax.inject.Singleton

@Singleton
class SwitchToIfFilter: DSTObfuscatorFilter {
    @Inject
    private lateinit var analyticContext: IAnalyticContext

    @Inject
    private lateinit var knownTypes: KnownTypeLibrary

    override fun visitDSTSwitchStatement(node: DSTSwitchStatement) {
        val expr = node.expression
        if (expr is DSTName && expr.binding is IVariableBinding && (expr.binding as IVariableBinding).type.isEnum)
            return

        val statements = node.statements
        val cases = node.statements.mapIndexed { index, dstStatement -> if (dstStatement is DSTSwitchCase) index to dstStatement else null }
                .filterNotNull()

        fun List<DSTStatement>.subListFrom(index: Int): List<DSTStatement> {
            val sublist = this.subList(index, this.size)
            val nextBreak = sublist.mapIndexed { index, dstStatement -> if (dstStatement is DSTBreakStatement) index to dstStatement else null }
                    .filterNotNull()
                    .firstOrNull()

            if (nextBreak != null) {
                return sublist.subList(0, nextBreak.first)
            }

            return sublist
        }

        var rootIfStatement: DSTIfStatement? = null
        var currentStatement: DSTIfStatement? = null

        for ((index, case) in cases) {
            if (rootIfStatement == null) {
                if (case.isDefault) {
                    return
                } else {
                    val condition = DSTSingleInfixExpression(knownTypes.booleanType, InfixExpression.Operator.EQUALS, case.expression!!, node.expression.clone())
                    val body = DSTBlockStatement(statements.subListFrom(index+1))
                    rootIfStatement = DSTIfStatement(condition, body, null)
                    currentStatement = rootIfStatement
                }
            } else {
                if (case.isDefault) {
                    currentStatement!!.thenStatement = DSTBlockStatement(statements.subListFrom(index+1))
                    break
                } else {
                    val condition = DSTSingleInfixExpression(knownTypes.booleanType, InfixExpression.Operator.EQUALS, case.expression!!, node.expression.clone())
                    val body = DSTBlockStatement(statements.subListFrom(index+1))
                    val ifStatement = DSTIfStatement(condition, body, null)
                    currentStatement!!.elseStatement = ifStatement
                    currentStatement = ifStatement
                }
            }
        }

        node.parent!!.replace(node, rootIfStatement!!)
        analyticContext.makeModification(this::class)
    }
}

According to the README, the example/out directory should have files after running successfully.
Here are my steps:

Clone the project.
Modify the runner/build.gradle file:
run { args = ['{$PATH}'] }
Run the command
gradle :runner:run

After executing these instructions I got these above errors
I know that the error means that the instance is not injected into the interface. But I don't know why can't inject it.
How else can I solve it?
